# MagicalRecord : how to perform background saves

Tags: ios, magicalrecord-2.1

I am building a news application, which basically fetches data from a distant server, using AFNetworkOperation (all operations are put in a NSOperationQueue in order to properly manage the synchronisation process and progress).

Each completion block of each AFNetworkOperation creates/deletes/updates core data entities.

At the whole end of the synchronisation process, in order to make all changes persistent, I perform a full save with following lines of code

```
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
         NSLog(@"saveInBackground : starting...");

         [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"saveInBackground : finished!");
         }];
    });
```

Unfortunately it always blocks the main thread during my save operation.

I might not use MagicalRecord properly and so any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deeper inside MagicalRecord, it seems that my code is working well and does not block main thread at all.

My issue is not on MagicalRecord, but on the way I should use it on completion blocks of afnetworking operation.

I Will start a new discussion to provide full details on it.